# Why is there a loop function in (Common) Lisp?

Tags: loops, recursion, clisp

Loops and recursion are of equal power. So why do we have a loop function in functional programming languages like Lisp? Is it because of the stack?

Comment: it's because you couldn't do loops otherwise, and sometimes looping is just more convenient than writing the equivalent recursive code. this has nothing to do with "the stack" (if any).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because some problems/structures are solved more efficiently by iterating over a set of data other by repeatingly performing a certain set of operations. 
Calculating fibonacci numbers is done more efficiently by iteration than by recursion, simply because it's not a good idea to calculate the same valaues over and over again, even if the stack space is not an issue.

So this

```
(defun recursive-fib (n)
  (if (<= n 2)
      1
      (+ (recursive-fib (- n 1))
         (recursive-fib (- n 2)))))
```

does the same as this

```
(defun iterative-fib (n)
  (do ((i n (- i 1)) 
       (fib1 1 (+ fib1 fib2)) 
       (fib2 1 fib1))
      ((<= i 2) fib1)))
```

but the second way is much more effcient.

Comment: `(defun interative-fib (n) (labels ((aux (n a b) (if (zerop n) a (aux (1- n) b (+ a b))))) (aux n 0 1)))` is a recursive solution that does not calculate any values twice.

Answer (score 3):

Common Lisp does not require tail call elimination. So an infinite loop could use unbounded amount of stack space if it were done using recursion.

In addition, CL provides a number of specialized looping constructs that reflect natural idioms: `DOLIST` and `MAPCAR` for iterating over list elements, `DOTIMES` for incrementing a counter, `DO-ALL-SYMBOLS` for iterating over all the symbols in a package, and `LOOP` which has clauses for many common operations.

The philosophy of Common Lisp is to provide high-level operations and data structures, so that programmers only have to implement the code for the application domain, not all the low-level operations.

Answer (score 2):

No, functional languages can do loops just as efficiently when you write them as recursion.

However, there's the question of meaning too. Some things are inherently loops (iterating over a list), while some things are inherently recursive (factorial). Both can be writen as each other, but when you've got both options, it's better to choose the one that shows the intent more clearly.

Also, you can do infinite loops with loop :D

Comment: You can do infinite loops  with TCO too. `(defun x () (x))` will run forever if it's compiled in most CL's.

Comment: @Sylwester True, but it just cries "smell" :D In a language with TCO, there isn't a loop you couldn't rewrite in a recursive form - and there isn't a recursive function you couldn't rewrite using a loop. It's just about choosing the option that's easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 2):

Common Lisp is a multi paradigm language and the standard does not require tail call  optimization. The `loop` macro is one of the loop constructs that does not blow the stack.

Historically Common Lisp was [not made from scratch](http://www.nhplace.com/kent/Papers/cl-untold-story.html). It combined many popular LISPs into one language. Most if the implementations had a solution to fight blown stack without having to make TCO.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the `LOOP` construct is a [macro](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LispMacro), not a function. Macros are more flexible than function definitions, because you can define your own syntax and evalutation rules for them.

You can consider `LOOP` as a small language-within-a-language that provides a higher-level way to express "looping over things". Using recursion to iterate or loop over things isn't necessarily more expressive in that regard, it depends on the nature of the problem.

You can learn more about `LOOP` [here](http://www.ai.sri.com/pkarp/loop.html).